# Highcharts empty Month

Tags: highcharts

I'm generating a highchart. First the highchart start with the month "November" That month is empty and looks right. Now if I go to the month "Juli" (IMAGE 1) (just a month with some points) it looks good, but now.. if I go back to the empty month "November" (IMAGE 2) I see the dots from the month "Juli".

To change the month:

```
line_chart_1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(start_date_time, end_date_time);
line_chart_1.redraw();
```

How to fix this?

[image: HighChart Bug]

Comment: Looks like your data isn't on the right format.

Comment: If I haven't any empty months everything is ok. So which data must contain an empty month?

Comment: You have to set the empties with null.